# Can we create asynchronous REST service with Restlet framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, restlet

I am trying to understand the asynchronous component of Restlet framework[2.3].
From [official site](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/introduction/features)

> Fully multi-threaded design with per-request Resource instances to reduce thread-safety issues when developing applications.
>
> Supports asynchronous request processing, decoupled from IO operations. Unlike the Servlet API, the Restlet applications don't have a direct control on the outputstream, they only provide output representation to be written by the server connector.
>
> Supports non-blocking NIO modes to decouple the number of connections from the number of threads.

so I don't understand the difference between the first and second sentences. For me the requests are handled by some connector(web container? like Jetty or NIO) and if connector is asynchronous, we're done. And finally I don't understand "non-blocking NIO mode", is NIO the same thing that NIO connector?
Maybe somebody can give an example of an asynchronous server based on Restlet(Official site contains a little information about this topic)?

Thanks.